# Converting 'Const' ReactJs components to class based with param

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, components

I have been improving the code with which I am learning to use class-based components. I had partial success with functions that have no parameters. But the rest were not converted.

**What worked:**

This

```
const About = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>About</h2>
  </div>
)
```

to

```
class About extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <h2>About</h2>
         <p>The content is here.</p>
       </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Yet to be done:**

The below component is where am stuck. I really can't understand how this param can be passed to the class-based method. Will params be available in constructor of the class as prop or something?

```
const Topic = ({match}) => (
  <div>
    <h3>{match.params.topicId}</h3>
  </div>
)
```

One more below.

```
const Topics = ({match}) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Topics</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/rendering`}>
          Rendering with React
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/components`}>
          Components
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/props-v-state`}>
          Props v. State
        </Link>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <Route path={`${match.url}/:topicId`} component={Topic}/>
    <Route exact path={match.url} render={() => (
    <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>
  )}/>
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert from a function component to a class component:

1. Move everything from the function component's body to the `render` method of the class component. If the body is the JSX itself, just `return` it from the `render` method.
2. Assign the props you need to constants by destructuring `this.props`.

**Note:** for view only components without state or need for life cycle methods, you should keep the stateless components.

**Topic before:**

```
const Topic = ({match}) => (
  <div>
    <h3>{match.params.topicId}</h3>
  </div>
)
```

**The converted Topic:**

```
class Topic extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { match } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <h3>{match.params.topicId}</h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To extend Ori Drori's solution (which is completely right) I want to give you some more context of the composition of components to understand WHERE the props come from (which is not answered yet).

So let's say you got a Topic component and a Topics component (List of Topics). Components are able to render other components, so Topics can render many Topic components.

With this in mind let's say our starting point is Topics:

```
class Topics extends React.Component {
    // In a typical single page application you will receive topics from outside, for example from a REST API.
    const topics = [{
        name: "Topic1",
        id:   1
    }, {
        name: "Topic2",
        id:   2
    }];

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    topics.map(topic => <Topic 
                        name={topic.name}
                        topicId={topic.id}
                    />)
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The Topic would look exactly the same than in Ori Drori's answer.

What seems to be a great way to compose components can become a real struggle when your application grows (so many dependencies and property bubbling), especially because you need a lot of data transformations between several component layers. This is where Redux or React Baobab comes in which offer an approach to remove data transformations as well as state transitions from the components into a centralized module - the state.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. @tobias